# Calculating the CSS with with iframes

Tags: html, css

I had the `frameset` on both sides of page, and i have a middle page

with the middle page, i am trying to check the width of the page to load content within a div and width should be calculated and if it is bigger, i can add an `overflow`, but it should not be too long,

asking this question because the right frame can be visible on a `condition` and cannot be

```
margin-left:5px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x:hidden;height:700px;display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of html elements with

```
$("selector").width()
$("selector").height()
```

you can just use those function , after all rendering is finished (the page must be loaded first).

At the bottom of the frame(s)

```
<script>
$(function(){
if(document.body.offsetWidth<$("selector").width()){
....
}else{
....
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: how can i implement that in a din so it happens with a div width management

Comment: i mean DIV so ican whre i can add it

Comment: that is strange, write a plugin

Comment: as you are using iframes, you the the calculations after page loads.

Comment: within iframe , window.parent accesses the page which includes the iframe. you can call a function to modify  iframes  in .... part of the code. hope this helps.